# BLToolkit PostgreSql connection error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, bltoolkit

I installed BLToolkit PostgreSql Data Provider 4.1.17 via package manager console. BlToolkit.4 is also installed to the project. But I couldn't connect to db yet. The error I encountered and web config is below. Any advice?

***Error String:***

```
key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString
```

***web.config:***

```
<configuration>
    <BLToolkit>
        <dataProviders>
            <add type="BLToolkit.Data.DataProvider.PostgreSQLDataProvider" />
        </dataProviders>
    </BLToolkit>
    <configSections>
        <section name="BLToolkit" type="BLToolkit.Configuration.BLToolkitSection, BLToolkit.Data.DataProvider.PostgreSQL.4" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DbCon"
             connectionString="Data Source=postgresql-x64-9.2;database=postgres;User Id=postgres; password=..."
             providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

***Connection:***

```
public class Database: DbManager
    {
        public Database() : base("DbCon")
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clearly the error message was referring to the `connectionString` attribute and yet you did not provided it (even an obfuscated version of it). Did you expect us to use a crystal ball to guess what's the issue?

Comment: I did'nt think it is about connection string when I had written the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was about connection string,

```
<add name="DbCon" providerName="Npgsql" connectionString="server=localhost;database=postgres;User Id=postgres; password=..." />
```

solved the problem.